# Ant build: import build.xml from sub-folders w/o overriding their properties

Tags: java, ant

I have an open-source project that I added to my project source. The oss-project currently builds stand-alone using ant and its build.xml.

I want to build this project as a part of my project. My directory structure looks like this:

```
my-project\
  build.xml
  oss-project\
     build.xml
     {all the code}
```

I tried to import the oss-project\build.xml into my-project\build.xml.

```
<import file="${source_base}/oss-project/build.xml"/>
```

My build.xml defines basedir, source.base etc. variables and the imported xml also contains these variables. But, when i try to build by running "ant" at my source root, while building the oss-project, it's using the variables defined in parent build.xml.

I could probably create unique names be prefixing all variables in my oss-project\build.xml with that project name. But, its starting to look ugly. And then hard to keep it in sync in future as well.

Is there a way by which the variables defined inside the child build.xml are not overridden by the once in parent build.xml?

Comment: What is your end goal? To have one jar with everything in it, or to build both projects in succession with one invocation of Ant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(in this case) You should not import build.xml. Instead it should delegate the child build to the appropriate build file. You can use [ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) for it

Your top level build should have entry like below..

```
   <ant dir="${source_base}/oss-project/"/>
```